# Was there a Clone Protocol Order worse than Order 66?

Tags: star-wars

I've been doing some research and was wondering if there was there ever an order worse than Order 66 in terms of evil and death? I've heard people say there was, but now I want a real answer.

Comment: This seems opinion based, how do we judge the evilness of the order?

Comment: Like if the clones start killing everyone ever tied to the republic.

Answer (score 5):

#### Order 37

> Order 37: Capture of a single wanted individual through the mass arrest and threatened execution of a civilian population. Follow-up directives include scenarios for body disposal of civilian casualties and suppression of communications.

This would be the only one I can see possibly being more evil. Whether or not it is "evil" is subjective, but it definitely unethical.

The ethics of betraying a comrade and the mass arrest and execution of civilians is like comparing apples to oranges. Legally speaking, however, Order 66, when acted on in good faith, is a good thing. Order 37 is just unethical from the beginning.

Comment: So...practically what they did on that one planet on the force awakens with the first order

Comment: Yes, sorta. I doubt that was specifically Order 37. But yes. In Legends you'll find Order 37 being used a lot to find and eliminate the Jedi who were missed by Order 66.

Comment: Huh never thought of it

Comment: Why can't fruit be compared?

Comment: It's a figure of speech.